# Getting Could not load Extension from error when launching Chrome using Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch Chrome using the below code.

```
WebDriver driver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "properties/chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("www.google.com");
```

When the program runs, the chrome is opened and I am getting the below error after that

Could not load extension from 
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4560_5259\internal.
Invalid value for permission[1].

Answer (score 0):

Please change below line in code :

driver.get("http://www.google.com");

Use Http with URL as per above.

Also please download latest chrome driver from below :

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

Replace above downloaded file to your properties folder and then run